# XPath 1.0 closest preceding and/or ancestor node with an attribute in a XML Tree

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Here are three XML-trees

(1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
   <section id="1">
        <section id="2"/>
        <section id="3"/>
        <section id="9"/>
    </section>
    <section id="4">
        <section id="5">
            <section>
                <bookmark/> <!-- here's the bookmark-->
                <section id="6">
                    <section id="7">
                        <section id="8"/>
                    </section>
               </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</content>
```

(2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
    <section id="1"/>
    <section id="2">
        <section id="9">
            <section id="10">
                <section id="11"/>
            </section>            
        </section>
        <section>
            <section id="4">
                <section id="5"/>
            </section>            
        </section>
        <section/>
        <bookmark/> <!-- here's the bookmark-->
        <section id="6">
            <section id="7">
                <section id="8"/>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</content>
```

The desired result is in both cases the id **5**.

With XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0 I can either get the ancestor from (1)

```
<xsl:value-of select="//bookmark/ancestor::*[@id][1]/@id"/>
```

or the preceding node from (2)

```
<xsl:value-of select="//bookmark/preceding::*[@id][1]/@id"/>
```

How do I get the **nearest** ancestor **or** preceding node with an id from my bookmark?
I need a single xsl:value-of which matches both cases. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The solution should also cover this structure. Desired id is still **5**.

(3)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
   <section id="1">
        <section id="2"/>
        <section id="3"/>
        <section id="9"/>
    </section>
    <section id="4">
        <section>
            <section id="10"/>
            <section id="5"/>
            <section>
                <bookmark/> <!-- here's the bookmark-->
                <section id="6">
                    <section id="7">
                        <section id="8"/>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</content>
```

Comment: Picture which shows all xpath axes: [pic](http://nwalsh.com/docs/tutorials/xsl/xsl/graphics/axes.gif)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted attribute node in all three cases. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Use**:

```
    (//bookmark/ancestor::*[@id][1]/@id 
| 
    //bookmark/preceding::*[@id][1]/@id
     )
     [last()]
```

**Verification**: Using XSLT as host of XPath, the following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "(//bookmark/ancestor::*[@id][1]/@id
  |
   //bookmark/preceding::*[@id][1]/@id
   )
    [last()]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any of the provided three XML documents, produces the wanted, correct result**:

`5`

**I strongly recomment using the [XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html) for playing with / learning XPath**.

Answer (score 3):

Try with :

```
<xsl:value-of 
    select="//bookmark/ancestor::*[1]/descendant-or-self::*[last()-1]/@id"/>
```

It returns `5` for both XML documents.

**EDIT:**

In such conditions you could use simple `xsl:choose`:

```
<xsl:variable name="lastSibling"
    select="//bookmark/preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$lastSibling">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="$lastSibling/descendant-or-self::*[last()]/@id"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="//bookmark/ancestor::*[@id][1]/@id"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Another general solution:

```
<xsl:for-each
    select="//section[following::bookmark or descendant::bookmark][@id]">
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Your solution works under special circumstances. But if I add more sections with id after bookmark on both XMLs your solution will give wrong results. Will edit my examples to have some sections after bookmark.

Comment: @therealmarv: Right. I assumed specific structure. Check my second solution.

Comment: @therealmarv: corrected `last()` → `1` in `lastSibling` variable.

Comment: Your solution is a good approach. It gives me some ideas. But it is not a general solution. I edited my examples again. The nearest ancestor is maybe not parent and the id can be somewhere in a child of a preceding node.

Comment: Wow. Your more general solution works for (1) and (3). Thanks alot! :-) But, it does not work for (2), the solution is empty. Still figuring out what's the reason. Hopefully I can solve it